# Laravel Request can't get values of some key

Tags: php, laravel, request

I am trying to retrieve some part of `request()` in my Form Request class named `StoreApplicantLanguage.php`. The request key called 'languages' and it has an array of objects containing a key-value pair to be stored in my `applicant_languages' table.

Here is my JSON request from Postman:

```
{
    "languages": [
        {
            "language": "English",
            "capability": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks normal right?! **But**, when I'm trying to get the values of the `languages` key like this:

```
$requestLanguages = request()->languages;
dd($requestLanguages);
```

, it shows **null**.
I tried to restart my server, do `php artisan config:cache`, but none are works. But when I change the key name in the request object to `language`, it works!

Also, the request object has another named field like `families`, and I can get the values inside by doing `request()->families`.

I have no idea at all how this can be happen. Anyone can explain my case, please!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: From Malkhazi Dartsmelidze's answer I realized that I misstyped the question. I didn't write comma after '1' value in my JSON request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my system.
Maybe you that's because you are passing invalid json.

```
{
    "languages": [
        {
            "language": "English",
            "capability": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Try passing this JSON (I deleted last comma after '1')

Also note that `Request` is object and there is properties that are used already and `$request`  variable can return it. You can use `$request->get('languages')` to get parameter from request

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not working in a Controller or method that using `$request` variable as an instance of `Request` as you said. But from your answer, now I can get the data with `languages` key by doing `$families = Request::get('families');`
Thanks a lot, sorry for my ignorance.